# How to call API in background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for API calling in my app.

Now I want to call some API in background thread so when that API is called, other functionality work propely. So how can I do this in Alamofire?

this is how I am calling APi

```
func GetDesignationList(pharmacyId : String,completion:(ManageDesignation : ManageDesignationListModel)-> Void)  {
let url = "\(VendorURL)all_employee_designation_list"
let param : [String : AnyObject] = [

    "pharmacyId" : pharmacyId
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: param, encoding: .URL).responseObject { (response:Response<ManageDesignationListModel, NSError>) in
    switch response.result
    {
    case.Success(let value) :
        var ManageDesignationObject : ManageDesignationListModel?
        ManageDesignationObject = value
        completion(ManageDesignation: ManageDesignationObject!)
    case.Failure(let error) : break

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can use dispatch_queues.

Comment: Alamofire itself will do it's job in the background thread so that you don't have to put your efforts there. Any other function you want executed while alamofire block is being done, you can just do it normally. You'll have a problem if you want alamofire results ASAP because it's an `Asynchronous` process and doesn't really wait for any other job to be done first.

Comment: ok @Dershowitz123 Alamofire do its all job in background thread??

Comment: Yes! It is an `Asynchronous` process which does its job on the background thread ensuring your UI wont freeze or slow down your app overall.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right already. Alamofire calls web services in background threads. If you want to test that it works asynchronlusly, you can add a `print("1")` after the call and a `print("2")` inside the `response` closure.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out Alamofire already does the job for you.

But to answer the question "*How to call API in background thread*"

**A class which can dispatch to different threads:**

```
class Dispatcher
{
    enum DispatchLevel
    {
        case Main, UserInteractive, UserInitiated, Utility, Background
        var dispatchQueue: OS_dispatch_queue {
            switch self {
            case .Main:             return dispatch_get_main_queue()
            case .UserInteractive:  return dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)
            case .UserInitiated:    return dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)
            case .Utility:          return dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)
            case .Background:       return dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0) }
        }
    }

    func delay(bySeconds seconds: Double, dispatchLevel: DispatchLevel = .Main, closure: () -> Void)
    {
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatchLevel.dispatchQueue, closure)
    }   
}
```

**Use it like:**

```
let myDispatch = Dispatcher()

myDispatch.delay(bySeconds: 10, dispatchLevel: .Background)
{
    print("Do something here on background thread")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call Web service and UI at same time**

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("webservice", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{


        // do our long running process here
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];


        // do any UI stuff on the main UI thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });


    });
```